# DropDownListFor with custom build list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a dropdown list wich value will be saved into my database.

For now, I have this working code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("YearSelection",new SelectList(new [] {"2002", "2003","2004"}))
```

But this is not right solution (the code is ugly - I need years from 2002 to 2015), and I want to save in my model. Maybe something like this (not tested yet):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.StartYearOfFaculty,new SelectList(new [] {"2002", "2003","2004"}))
```

2. Other approach that I've created but I don't know how to call it correct:

Model:

```
 namespace DataAccess{

[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMD))]
public partial class Employee{
public List <StartYearFaculty> StartYearOFFaculty { get; set; }
}

public class StartYearFaculty{

public int yearOfStartFaculty { get; set; }
}
}
```

Controller - Employee/Create

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();

        emp.StartYearOFFaculty = new List<StartYearFaculty>();
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2002 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2003 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2004 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2005 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2006 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2007 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2008 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2009 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2010 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2011 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2012 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2013 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2014 });
        emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new StartYearFaculty() { yearOfStartFaculty = 2015 });
        var a = emp.StartYearOFFaculty;

        ViewBag.StartYearFaculty = emp.StartYearOFFaculty;
       return View();
    }
```

And in my View:

```
@using System.Collections
@using DataAccess
@model DataAccess.Employee

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartEduYear, "Entrance study year", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.DropDownList("StartYearFaculty", null, "--Please choose coresponding level--", new { @class = "form-control" })*@
           @*@Html.DropDownList("MyDropDown",new SelectList(new [] {"sdsd", "sdfsd","sdfsdf"}))*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StartYearOFFaculty,Model.StartYearOFFaculty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartEduYear, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And therefore is an error about IEnumerable type:

> CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Side note: You can use `new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(2002, 14))` to generate the `SelectList` (although that code should be in the controller, not the view)

Answer (score 2):

First - you really should not use your DAL classes on your View. And for `DropDownListFor` helper it will be better to use `SelectListItem` class for your data collection.

But if you still want to use custom class you should specify what fields will be `Text` and `Value` from your collection like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.yearOfStartFaculty 
, new SelectList(Model.StartYearOFFaculty,"yearOfStartFaculty","yearOfStartFaculty"));
```

Note that your model, that you define at the begin of your view **MUST have `yearOfStartFaculty` property**. You don't have it now. This property should be `string` or `int` and represent selected value.

But again it's better to create separate ViewModel and create there a field:

```
public List <SelectListItem> StartYearOFFaculty { get; set; }
```

instead of:

```
public List <StartYearFaculty> StartYearOFFaculty { get; set; }
```

So your `ViewModel` class could look like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public List<SelectListItem> StartYearOFFaculty { get; set; }
   public int SelectedYear { get; set; }
}
```

If you do it like this and populete it your controller you will be able to do it easily:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedYear, Model.StartYearOFFaculty);
```

Comment: I am trying to do it by your example, but it says that it cannot resolve a symbol for Selected year, when I try to populate a list: `emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new SelectListItem() { SelectedYear = 2002 });`

Comment: @Stefan0309 can't understand what you mean, can you explain more? But it will be much easier for you to use ViewModel anyway...

Comment: SelectedYear is marked as red. It cannot find property SelectedYear, which I added into my Model..thanks.

Comment: @Stefan0309 have you change definition of your model at the begin of your View?

Comment: I cant build it..its an error in my controller `Error 2 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedYear'`

Comment: this my updated controller: ` Employee emp = new Employee();

            emp.StartYearOFFaculty = new List<SelectListItem>();
            emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new SelectListItem() { SelectedYear = 2002});`

Comment: no. no no... you should create it like this `new SelectListItem{ Text = "2002", Value = "2002" }`

Comment: Yess...just now, I've tried and get this ` emp.StartYearOFFaculty.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2002", Value = "1" });` thanks! But I don't know why I entered this SelectedYear property..its not neccessary..